# Repeater Item command creating post back  with Update Panel

Tags: asp.net

I have update panel in that I have repeater control with linkbutton which are having command property

I have tried both ItemCommand event or link button click both are creating postbacks

Here the code for that

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upFC" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Repeater ID="rptFCItem" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptFCItem_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptFCItem_ItemCommand" EnableViewState="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkElement" runat="server" OnClick="lnkCurrent_Click" CommandName="Element"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
```

and following is server side code

```
  protected void lnkCurrent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindFC(Element, true);
    }


 protected void rptFCItem_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemIndex >= 0)
        {
            LinkButton lnkElement = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkElement");
            if (lnkElement != null)
            {
                lnkElement.Text = (e.Item.ItemIndex+1).ToString();
            }
        }
    }

protected void rptFCItem_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
       //some code here
    }
```

But neither itemcommand work or click event works with update panel async its creating full postback.

Does any one have solution for it.

Best Regards,

Jalpesh

Comment: Do you receive any javascript error in the page ?! Are you sure that the ajax is doing any request ?!

Comment: From [what I found](http://forums.asp.net/t/1029795.aspx/1/10?Problems+with+Repeater+ItemCommand+Event+and+UpdatePanel+Triggers) it's a bug in update panel regarding update mode. Does it work if `updatemode="conditional"`? [More Reading](http://forums.asp.net/p/580720/1909340.aspx) & [yet more reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y200hyx2%28vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: I had tried both conditional and always

Answer (score 0):

In the code posted above you have registered the event in Markup as OnItemCommand="rptFlashCardItem_ItemCommand"

In the code behind, the name differs as 'rptFCItem_ItemCommand'. Does this existing code give you an error at compile time? If yes, it could be a name mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

If you swap out the Repeater for a ListView it works.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upFC" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListView ID="rptFCItem" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptFCItem_ItemDataBound"
                OnItemCommand="rptFCItem_ItemCommand" EnableViewState="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkElement" runat="server" OnClick="lnkCurrent_Click" CommandName="Element"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You'll also need to replace the repeater event args with the ListView versions.

```
protected void rptFCItem_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.DataItemIndex >= 0)
    {
        LinkButton lnkElement = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkElement");
        if (lnkElement != null)
        {
            lnkElement.Text = (e.Item.DataItemIndex + 1).ToString();
        }
    }
}

protected void rptFCItem_ItemCommand(object source, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // some code here
}
```

I think the reason it doesn't work with a repeater has to do with the fact that repeaters don't provide the same naming structure inside of them as the other list type controls.

Comment: I have tried list view also. Its not working but never mind i have figure it out with datalist.